# Upload multiple attachments using Messenger Send API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-send-api

I want to use Facebook Messenger API to send multiple images in a single message. I have those files as Temp files on rails app server. I found this [Attaching a file](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages#file), which provides the following way of sending a file as attachment

```
curl  \
  -F 'recipient={"id":"<PSID>"}' \
  -F 'message={"attachment":{"type":"<ASSET_TYPE>", "payload":{"is_reusable":true}}}' \
  -F 'filedata=@/tmp/shirt.png;type=image/png' \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/me/messages?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

but it specifies only one file to be uploaded, hence I cannot use it. 
Moreover, there's this [Deprecated List Template](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/templates/list) but I cannot use this since it is deprecated. Is there a way to send multiple file attachments in one message using messenger platform's API?

Comment: If you want to send multiple images, you can also use generic template. And place necessary buttons to download those images if user wants to.

Comment: is it now possible to read direct messages of account that is using Send API app to analyze the DMs??